# How to find out if a ComboBox contains any items?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have simple WinForms application in C# which has two controls: `combobox1` and `button`. I would like to find out if there are any items in `combobox1`.

I have tried this, but it only tells me if there is a selected item:

```
if (combobox1.Text != ""))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Combo is not empty");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Double click on your button in the Form and insert this code inside the click event handler :  `

```
        //this code should work
        if (comboBox1.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your combo is empty");
        }

   `
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `combobox1.Items.Count == 0`? I don't think you can have a negative count.

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem!=null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Combo is not empty");
}
```

to determine if something is selected

And I use this to determine if the comboBox has any items.

```
if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your combo is not empty");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If no item selected/Present, then SelectedIndex property returns -1.

```
  if (combobox1.SelectedIndex == -1) 
    //no item selected/present
```

Comment: then combobox1.Items.Count could help you

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am sure if you check out ComboBox class on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox_properties, it'd benefit you.

Also, personally I wouldn't tend to use `selectedIndex` or `selectedItem` property, as there can be a case where item collection is not empty but none of any items are actually selected. Use `items.count` is a better way to decide if item collection is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ComboBox.Items!=null && ComboBox.Items.Count>0)
{
  //have some item 
}
```

and if you need to know how many item have Use

```
string Count = ComboBox.Items.Count;
```